# Function always return null

Tags: php

I'm not sure why, but I've created a function and somehow it never return anything.
It supposed to return a random number generated by using the mt_rand() function.
I modified the code and tried to run it on ideone and the results says runtime error, signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

```
<?php
    function breedingTree($name, $N, $max) 
    {
        include('config.php');
        if ($N < $max AND $name > 0) 
        {

            $sql = 'SELECT sire, dam
                    FROM '.$prefix.'owned_adoptables
                    WHERE aid = "'.$name.'"';
            $res = mysql_query($sql);
            list($s, $d) = mysql_fetch_row($res);
            if (mt_rand(0,1) === 1) breedingTree($s, $N+1, $max);
            else breedingTree($d, $N+1, $max);

        }
        elseif ($name <= 0)
        {

            if ($N === 0) return mt_rand(1,100);
            elseif ($N === 1) return mt_rand(5,95);
            elseif ($N === 2) return mt_rand(15,85);
            elseif ($N === 3) return mt_rand(25,75);

        }

    }

echo breedingTree(355, 0, 4); // Return nothing
echo breedingTree(0, 0, 4); // Return random number between 1 - 100
?>
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. If nothing gets returned, it is probably because `$name` is `> 0`. What  do `$name`, `$N` and `$max` contain?

Comment: Don't your recursive calls to breedingTree() need to return values?  Otherwise how will the value propagate back up?

Comment: Some pointers of areas your code could be problematic -- (1) recursive function with SQL query in it may be pretty bad for performance if you recurse a lot (2) including a php file within your function will scope everything to your function and execute all code in that php file inside your function.

Comment: I would also suspect the mysql_query call is not going to work on ideone.

Comment: Also look into debug_backtrace for debugging if you don't have any kind of IDE

Comment: The function is doing way too much. Get rid of the include and refactor the function to actually just do one thing instead of doing setup, db querying and randomizing. That will make finding bugs much simpler.

Comment: @MarkBiek Thanks, solved another piece of recursive code I was writing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if `$N` is not 0, 1, 2, or 3, or if `($N < $max AND $name > 0)`, or if `($N >= max AND $name > 0)`?  There is no `return` statement for those code paths.

Comment: $N will never reach above 4 actually. Because the $max will only be specified between 0 to 4. And $s and $d ($name) will eventually reach 0. I've tried to replace those returns with echo(). And the code seems to be working just fine. It echo the random number, but return() didn't return anything.

Comment: @Kemal: Ok.  But you should have those code paths assert, or throw an exception or something, to document that they cannot happen.  But that still leaves the fact that there is no return statement inside the `if ($N < $max AND $name > 0)`...

Comment: Ok thanks. I've put the return statements inside the first if statement and now it's working!